# Java error: "Cannot instantiate the type..." and type mismatch

Tags: java, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

How can I get rid of the error "Cannot instantiate the type..."?

I have an abstract class named `Expression`:

```
public abstract class Expression {
    private String expr;
        
    Expression(){}
    
    Expression(String expr){
        this.expr = expr;
    }
    
    public String getExpr() {
        return this.expr;
    }
}
```

And I have a class that inherits `Expression`:

```
public class Elements extends Expression {
    private List<String> elements = new ArrayList<>();
    
    Elements(List<String> elements){
        this.elements = elements;
    }
    
    public List<String> getElements(){
        return this.elements;
    }
}
```

And I also have a class that extends a generic class with parameter type `Expression`, and a method of return type `Expression` (this generic class is just a class generated by a parser generator):

```
public class AntlrToExpression extends ExprBaseVisitor<Expression> {
@Override
public Expression visitElements(ElementsContext ctx) {
        ElementContext element;
        List<String> elemList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        ElementsContext elements = ctx.elements();
        while(elements.getChildCount() > 1) {
            element = elements.element();
            elemList.add(element.getText());
            elements = elements.elements();
        }
        element = elements.element();
        elemList.add(element.getText());
        
        return new Elements(elemList); // Here I get errors saying "Cannot instantiate the type Elements" and "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Elements to Expression"
    }
}
```

All the classes above are defined in the same package. Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Ok, just figured out that the reason was because the class name `Elements` conflicted with a built-in Java class.

Comment: Hi @rikki,
I recreated the classes above locally and created a unit test. I did not run into a "Cannot instantiate" issue.  Technically you can return an Elements instance because Elements is an Expression.  
Can you double check your import declaration in AntlrToExpression class making sure that imports are correct?

Comment: LOL. I missed your previous comment by 2 min. I had a stale record :-).

Comment: Yeah I had a wrong import that's what was causing the error. Thank you.

Comment: @rikki I am assuming the last class was something you created using ANTLR? What version of ANTLR are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Credit Makoto

You can't instantiate an abstract class.

You've got two options:

- Remove abstract from the class declaration, or
- Create another class to extend Expression, which can be instantiated.

Comment: I was about to post something similar. The error itself relates the problem clearly `"Cannot instantiate the type Elements" ..."`.

Comment: Extend `Garage`? LOL I don't think so.

Comment: I'm instantiating a class that extends an abstract class, not the abstract class itself. That's legal right?

Comment: @rikki You have two problems as indicated by the error message. 1) An instantiation problem, and 2) a type mismatch problem. An `Elements` object is-a `Expression` type. HOWEVER, not all `Expression` objects are of type `Elements`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe somewhere in your code, you try to instantiate Expression object.  Since the Expression class is abstract, it cannot be instantiated.  But these types of errors are caught by the IDE and at compilation.

It would help if you include the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: This is not an answer. It is a comment. In the future, use the comments section to post these kind of comments and wait until the question is refined to post the (final) answer.

Comment: Sorry, I am new and do not have enough credits to comments.

Comment: Still, don't post comments as answers. I don't believe in this practice, but others will downvote your "answer" and without the courtesy of telling you why. Just don't post until you can provide a real answer. This could've been a real answer if you would've not use words like "Maybe". Be assertive (that was the actual problem), but also take time to look and point out where the issue is. That's what Brentspine actually did.

Comment: True.  A comment to get clarification before providing an answer would be the way to go.

Comment: I just want to help you out. I have been around long enough to know how some people operate here. I hate to see people losing reputation points for trying to help. That's why I didn't downvote your answer. I don't operate that way.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning `Expression` in the visitElements but try to return a `new Element()`

Comment: This is the second part of the problem (the type mismatch)

Comment: Delete this answer and update your original answer with this information

Comment: @hfontanez any idea how to fix this issue yourself? Or are you just commenting

Comment: I am agreeing with your statements. Both of your posts seem to be right on.